# broke Ubuntu with the Windows disk management tool

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-8, system-installation

I initially had 3 partitions:
-Windows 7
-Ubuntu
-Data (no OS)

I had grub2 as a boot loader.

I used the default Windows disk management tool to shrink my Data partition and install Windows 8. After shrinking my Data partition and creating a new one, i restarted my computer and I got an error message telling me that it encountered an error (grub didn't even start). So I installed Windows 8, and I can now dual boot 7 and 8 with the Windows 8 boot loader. In the windows disk management tool I see that the Ubuntu partitions are 100% free, which is odd, since I only formatted the new partition.

1. What did I do wrong? Was I supposed to create the partition using gparted?
2. I now want to install Ubuntu again. Is there a chance that now I'll somehow erase my Windows partition by accident?
3. I assume grub will automatically install again, so is it compatible with Windows 8?

Comment: ubuntu partition is there but widnows won't see it as it does not support linux partitions. try to reinstall grub to access it

Comment: That would ONLY solve all my problems. It wont answer my first question.

Comment: Windows often updates partition table and erases the Linux entry as it does not see it. If shown as unallocated space you may be able to use testdisk to just restore partition. Post from Ubuntu live installer: sudo parted -l

Comment: I'll get back to you tomorrow, when I download the installer and test this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 No you did not wrong. Windows can't handle Linux filesystems. It just displays them as free.

3 Grub can boot Windows 8

2 You don't have to. 
a. Reinstall grub from a Live CD/DVD/USB-Stick. Grub will start first and than boot Ubuntu or Win.
Instructions: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd
b. Add a boot entry to the Windows bootloader.
Instructions: http://apcmag.com/how-to-dual-boot-windows-8-and-linux.htm

And yes, there is allways a chance to do something wrong. So do a backup!